# How can I go from this data: the line TS and the line TR are perpendicular, to this assertion: the triangle TSR is a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I need to use arguments, definitions and geometric facts.

In class, we use something called: diagram-deduction, it has three columns: in the first one we place the data that we know, e.i. the data I put in the title. In the middle column we place the arguments, definitions and geometric facts and the last one is what can be concluded. We recycle the conclusions and use them as input in the first column to continue the process. I don't know if anyone uses this system or something more efficient.

We also learnt the Principle of substitution, which is use in the middle column to relate two inputs.

What I have so far is that the first fact, about the perpenducular lines, using the definition about this kind of lines gives me as a conclusion that the angle created with STR is a right angle. Then, using the definition of angles I know that this is determined by the ray ST union the ray TR.

The idea that I have is to reach a point in which I can use the geometric fact about two coplanar points and that there's only one line that contains them, to relate the two previous rays and conclude that if I take any point in each ray it will create a new line that'll determine a right triangle. But I don't know how to continue.

(I apologize about the mistakes in the writing, I'm not completely sure of the translation of some terms to English and I would really appreciate any help, or a better or new way to see the deduction)

Comment: It's a little hard to help since you are obviously working within a certain proof/deduction framework. But if you have that STR is a right angle, you know that S and R are distinct (because the lines cross in only one point) and three distinct non-co-linear points will form a triangle... so I'm not sure what other steps you need.

Comment: You're right. I reasoned in a similar way.
What other ways do you know to approach this?

Comment: I am wondering can the contrapositive argument be accepted.